# Get the name of a monitor

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm having a bit of trouble retrieving the name of a monitor with winapi.  According to other entries on stackoverflow, the correct way to get the name of a monitor is this:

```
EnumDisplayDevices(nullptr, 0, &oDisplayDevice, 0);

char lpszDeviceName[32];
memcpy(lpszDeviceName, oDisplayDevice.DeviceName, 32);

EnumDisplayDevices(lpszDeviceName, 0, &oDisplayDevice, 0);

char lpszMonitorName[128];
memcpy(lpszMonitorName, oDisplayDevice.DeviceString, 128);
```

However, `EnumDisplayDevices` returns `FALSE` the second time around.  The first time around, `DeviceName` is `\\DISPLAY1` and `DeviceString` is the GPU vendor.  Using the `MONITORINFOEX` struct gives me the same value as `DeviceName`.

To be clear I'm looking for something like "Samsung blah blah," or what appears in the control panel on the screen resolution page.

Comment: Are you initializing `oDisplayDevice.cb` to `sizeof(oDisplayDevice)`?

Comment: Yes - I even Zero'd the memory and reassigned it between calls and it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This seems to return the proper data for me:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    DISPLAY_DEVICE dd;
    dd.cb = sizeof(dd);
    int deviceIndex = 0;
    while(EnumDisplayDevices(0, deviceIndex, &dd, 0))
    {
        std::string deviceName = dd.DeviceName;
        int monitorIndex = 0;
        while(EnumDisplayDevices(deviceName.c_str(), monitorIndex, &dd, 0))
        {
            std::cout << dd.DeviceName << ", " << dd.DeviceString << "\n";
            ++monitorIndex;
        }
        ++deviceIndex;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

If you're compiling for UNICODE then use this instead:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    DISPLAY_DEVICE dd;
    dd.cb = sizeof(dd);
    int deviceIndex = 0;
    while(EnumDisplayDevices(0, deviceIndex, &dd, 0))
    {
        std::wstring deviceName = dd.DeviceName;
        int monitorIndex = 0;
        while(EnumDisplayDevices(deviceName.c_str(), monitorIndex, &dd, 0))
        {
            std::wcout << dd.DeviceName << L", " << dd.DeviceString << L"\n";
            ++monitorIndex;
        }
        ++deviceIndex;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Here's an example of the output:

> \.\DISPLAY1\Monitor0, Dell U2410(DP)
> \.\DISPLAY2\Monitor0, Dell
>   2407WFP-HC (Digital)

Comment: I still get nothing.  I'm using LPWSTR (or std::wstring) and the W version of the function instead of a plain LPSTR, could that be why?

Comment: Hmm... I tried switching to non-wide strings and I got Generic PnP monitor, is that just because there's no vendor string?

Comment: I added a Unicode example.  For me, this returns the same strings I see in the display control panel and device manager.  Presumably if you're using the generic driver for the monitor then it would show the generic string.

Comment: Would pretty much every external monitor be something besides Generic PnP?  I'm trying to use this as a way to distinguish a monitor preference during the startup of my program.

Comment: It's hard to say.  The 3 monitors I currently have available all have specific drivers for them, but I have seen the generic driver in use before.  I would assume that unless they start switching cables around the combination of the device name and string would be a unique identifier.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me on Win10. "Retired Ninja" answer returned `Generic PnP monitor`.

Don't forget to add `DEFINES += "WINVER=0x0601"` or define that

```
#include <windows.h>

void QueryDisplay()
{
    std::vector<DISPLAYCONFIG_PATH_INFO> paths;
    std::vector<DISPLAYCONFIG_MODE_INFO> modes;
    UINT32 flags = QDC_ONLY_ACTIVE_PATHS;
    LONG isError = ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER;

    UINT32 pathCount, modeCount;
    isError = GetDisplayConfigBufferSizes(flags, &pathCount, &modeCount);

    if( isError )
    {
        return;
    }

    // Allocate the path and mode arrays
    paths.resize(pathCount);
    modes.resize(modeCount);

    // Get all active paths and their modes
    isError = QueryDisplayConfig(flags, &pathCount, paths.data(), &modeCount, modes.data(), nullptr);

    // The function may have returned fewer paths/modes than estimated
    paths.resize(pathCount);
    modes.resize(modeCount);


    if ( isError )
    {
        return;
    }

    // For each active path
    int len = paths.size();
    for( int i=0 ; i<len ; i++ )
    {
        // Find the target (monitor) friendly name
        DISPLAYCONFIG_TARGET_DEVICE_NAME targetName = {};
        targetName.header.adapterId = paths[i].targetInfo.adapterId;
        targetName.header.id = paths[i].targetInfo.id;
        targetName.header.type = DISPLAYCONFIG_DEVICE_INFO_GET_TARGET_NAME;
        targetName.header.size = sizeof(targetName);
        isError = DisplayConfigGetDeviceInfo(&targetName.header);

        if( isError )
        {
            return;
        }
        QString mon_name = "Unknown";
        if( targetName.flags.friendlyNameFromEdid )
        {
            mon_name = QString::fromStdWString(
                       targetName.monitorFriendlyDeviceName);
        }

        qDebug() << "Monitor " << mon_name;
    }
}
```